# Python- Split out src IP, src Port, dest IP, dest Port and create a dictionary

Tags: python, file, text, dictionary, split

So I have opened my file and split each line into a list using the readlines() module but I am trying to get each source IP, src port, dest IP and dest port out of the readlines(). Basically what I am being asked to do is: "open the provided dump file and split out each line for the src and dest IPs as well as the src and dest ports". Furthermore, "Create a dictionary called Hosts; the keys of hosts will be the IPs parsed from the file (both src and dest). The value for each key will be a two element list where the first item will be how many times an IP is the source and the seconds is how many times an IP is the destination".

Here is part of parsed file...

```
08:43:56.558781 IP 192.168.233.128.56779 > 50.116.53.73.80: Flags [S], seq 3055452145, win    29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 82505 ecr 0,nop,wscale 10], length 0
08:43:56.592590 IP 50.116.53.73.80 > 192.168.233.128.56779: Flags [S.], seq 1586785220, ack 3055452146, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
08:43:56.592688 IP 192.168.233.128.56779 > 50.116.53.73.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
08:43:56.700460 IP 192.168.233.128.56779 > 50.116.53.73.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:300, ack 1, win 29200, length 299
08:43:56.701082 IP 50.116.53.73.80 > 192.168.233.128.56779: Flags [.], ack 300, win 64240, length 0
08:43:57.034951 IP 50.116.53.73.80 > 192.168.233.128.56779: Flags [P.], seq 1:1395, ack 300, win 64240, length 1394
08:43:57.034976 IP 192.168.233.128.56779 > 50.116.53.73.80: Flags [.], ack 1395, win 32062, length 0
08:43:57.118796 IP 192.168.233.128.56780 > 50.116.53.73.80: Flags [S], seq 3778524509, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 82645 ecr 0,nop,wscale 10], length 0
```

FYI the file is formatted like this:

IP (source.Sourceport) > (dest.Destport)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os

while True:
try:
    f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Pys/ascii_dump.txt"))
    print ("It Opened!")
    break
except:
    print ("Cannot Open!")
    break

lines = f.readlines()
```

UPDATE
Now I am looking for the best way to split a str (one line) at one char to another char. So say split it at a ":" to the next ":".

Comment: Right, so try adding some code to parse the lines.  Or hire a dev.

Comment: Well, the last line doesn't do you any good; `readlines()` doesn't "split out each line", it just copies all of those lines, exactly as-is, into a list, which is no better than the iterable you already had (the file). And meanwhile, you haven't written any attempt at iterating over the lines, or splitting each line, or parsing the parts you've split. So, you're just asking us to do your assignment for you.

Comment: If you need some hints to get started: Each line in the file is a `str`; you can do all the splitting and parsing with nothing but one or two of the standard [`str` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Or you can make it a bit more compact with a regular expression, but if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it. If you try it either way and get stuck, then you'll have a good question to ask on SO.

Comment: Thanks so much John! I'll take that into consideration!

Comment: The problem here is I literally have no idea where to go. I know I can iterate through the file with a for loop but it is just splitting at IP. So maybe I can split at whatever charter number the start of the IP is to the end of the IP and do the same for port. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to look at the string's split method

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read()
lines = lines.split("\n")
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) > 0:
        srcIp = line[2]
        dstIp = line[4]
        print(srcIp.split('.'),dstIp.split('.'))
```

gives:

```
['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779'] ['50', '116', '53', '73', '80:']
['50', '116', '53', '73', '80'] ['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779:']
['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779'] ['50', '116', '53', '73', '80:']
['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779'] ['50', '116', '53', '73', '80:']
['50', '116', '53', '73', '80'] ['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779:']
['50', '116', '53', '73', '80'] ['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779:']
['192', '168', '233', '128', '56779'] ['50', '116', '53', '73', '80:']
['192', '168', '233', '128', '56780'] ['50', '116', '53', '73', '80:']
```

Comment: @user3002598, is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: No your answer was good. I just hadn't visited Stack in awhile. Got the question done and all is well. Thanks!